# ActiveMQ, why RedeliveryCounter dont increase when shutdown consumer before Ack

Tags: java, activemq-classic

My consumer running in a application server. This my ActiveMq config:

```
optimizeAcknowledge=true  
optimizeAcknowledgeTimeOut=5000  
destination=queue.test.msg?consumer.prefetchSize=10
```

After I sent 10 messages, the "Web Console(http://localhost:8161/admin)" could see 3 messages dont Ack(used optimizeAcknowledge), At this time when I restarted the consumer server, I received the 3 message again and the RedeliveryCounter=0. So I dont determine this is the redelivery messages or just sent by producer.

This question is also find in transaction. I run the test class: org\apache\activemq\RedeliveryPolicyTest.java, methoed:testRepeatedRedeliveryReceiveNoCommit. debug in "connection.close();" and stop it. The message's RedeliveryCounter is also "0".

***Question: So when I actually determine a message is redelivery or not, I must use a store save all message's id after consumer processed it and check if exist when a consumer received a message?***

The code is below:

```
public void testRepeatedRedeliveryReceiveNoCommit() throws Exception {
    connection.start();
    Session dlqSession = connection.createSession(true, Session.SESSION_TRANSACTED);
    ActiveMQQueue destination = new ActiveMQQueue("TEST");
    MessageProducer producer = dlqSession.createProducer(destination);

    // Send the messages
    producer.send(dlqSession.createTextMessage("1st"));

    dlqSession.commit();
    MessageConsumer dlqConsumer = dlqSession.createConsumer(new ActiveMQQueue("ActiveMQ.DLQ"));

    final int maxRedeliveries = 4;
    for (int i=0;i<=maxRedeliveries +1;i++) {

        connection = (ActiveMQConnection)factory.createConnection(userName, password);
        connections.add(connection);
        // Receive a message with the JMS API
        RedeliveryPolicy policy = connection.getRedeliveryPolicy();
        policy.setInitialRedeliveryDelay(0);
        policy.setUseExponentialBackOff(false);
        policy.setMaximumRedeliveries(maxRedeliveries);

        connection.start();
        Session session = connection.createSession(true, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
        MessageConsumer consumer = session.createConsumer(destination);

        ActiveMQTextMessage m = ((ActiveMQTextMessage)consumer.receive(4000));
        if (i<=maxRedeliveries) {
            m.setRedeliveryCounter(1);
            System.out.println("Text:"+ m.getText());
            System.out.println("RedeliveryCounter:" + m.getRedeliveryCounter());
        } else {
            System.out.println("null on exceeding redelivery count:" + m);
        }
        connection.close();
        connections.remove(connection);
    }

    // We should be able to get the message off the DLQ now.
    TextMessage m = (TextMessage)dlqConsumer.receive(1000);
    System.out.println("Got message from DLQ:" + m);
    System.out.println("Text:"+ m.getText());
    String cause = m.getStringProperty(ActiveMQMessage.DLQ_DELIVERY_FAILURE_CAUSE_PROPERTY);
    System.out.println("cause exception has policy ref:" +  cause.contains("RedeliveryPolicy"));
    dlqSession.commit();
}
```